# How binding brush color to color resource?

Tags: wpf, xaml

i want to bind color from SolidColorBrush and define Color resource from that.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBrush" Color="#FFF3F3F3"/>
<Color x:Key="MyColor" {how i bind brush color here?} />
```

or just i want to use the color in somewhere like in a ColorAnimation:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBrush" Color="#FFF3F3F3"/>

<Storyboard x:Key="MyStoryboard">
  <ColorAnimation To="{Binding Color, Source={StaticResource MyBrush}}" Duration="0:0:1"
.
.
.
/>
</Storyboard>
```

i have this error:

'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception.'

Comment: The ColorAnimation.To binding works well for me. Your problem is certainly somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You usually do it the other way round:

```
<Color x:Key="MyColor">#FFF3F3F3</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBrush" Color="{StaticResource MyColor}"/>
```

---

If you only have the SolidColorBrush and want to reuse its Color somewhere, you could always do it by a Binding like this:

```
Color="{Binding Color, Source={StaticResource MyBrush}}"
```

Comment: thanks for answer.
but i want to do that reverse
is it possible ?

Comment: Which doesn't make much sense. You can't bind the A, R, G and B properties of a Color, because they aren't dependency properties.

Comment: i know.. in vs i can set SolidColorBrush color visually by color picker but i can't do it for color.

Comment: yes actually i want to use it on ColorAnimation
but still i can't do it and i have error:
 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception.'